# Why is Egypt being the peace-keeper?

Tags: international-relations, armed-conflict

Egypt has taken initiative to hold peace talks between Israel and Palestine on various occasions. What is their interest in the matter? Is it simply a case of proximity, or does conflict between Israel and Palestine cause internal conflict within Egypt? Or, even more complicated, is Egypt being utilized by Western powers?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Being peace maker enhances Egypts' position.

   Ever since Gamal Abdel Nasser, Egypt was interested in being the leader of Arab world.

   Playing peace-keeper in what's considered as the among the most consequential  conflict grants both actual (everyone owes them favors) and perceived (they are a leader because they are able to do this) power.
2. Egypt is definitely affected by any conflict between Israel and HAMAS (which is an offshoot of Muslim Brotherhood Egyptian organization - google how they relate to the last 5 years in Egyptian politics)
3. They are definitely hoping that Western powers will be more favorable towards them  - see the "favors accrued" point in #1 bullet. That's not a push from Western government per se but that is a factor in their calculations.
4. Any disruption in Gaza strip negatively reflects on Egypt (terrorists going to Egypt; refugees escaping there, etc...).

Comment: I would add a 4th bullet... They do not want palestinian refugees in their country.

Comment: Egypt is also an ally to Palestine and really would rather not get pulled into a war with Israel again.

Comment: @Ryathal - for some values of the word "ally" :)